# Some clarification on a database design issue please, How much to use one table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a "**LibraryItem**" which is linked to a "**Library**" Table:

```
Library-<LibraryItem>-Organisation.
```

I use the **LibraryItem** table for many different types of *LibraryItems*, and also each *LibrayItem* is linked to an *organisation*. I now realise that I need to provide personal user libraries, and I could use the **LIbraryItem** table to hold *Personal Library Item* records as well. Each record would need a *UserId* as a FK. However my concern is that this **LibrayItem** table is now being used for many different *LibraryItem* types, particularly holding *system LibraryItem* records as well as *Personal* records. Perhaps I should not worry as this is what a DB is about?

Thoughts appreciated,

Thanks.

EDIT:

To simplify things, I may end up using different DB Views, for different types of "LibraryItem"  for CRUD actions.

Answer (score 0):

In the ORM world there are two common ways to map inheritance hierarchies. You did not mention using an ORM, however these patterns apply regardless.

You have a LibraryItem, and then a PersonalLibraryItem and SystemLibraryItem, both of which are types of LibraryItem.

In table-per-hierarchy (TPH) mapping the entire inheritance hierarchy in mapped to a single table. Here you have a single LibraryItemtable to hold PersonalLibraryItem and SystemLibraryItem.

```
CREATE TABLE LibraryItem
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    -- Shared by all types 
    Title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   -- Shared by all types 
    UserID INT NULL                 -- Only used by PersonalLibraryItem, and therefore is NULLable.
    SystemItemAttr INT NULL         -- Only used by SystemLibraryItem, and therefore is NULLable.
)
```

Pros: Fewer tables and so fewer joins and faster queries (usually)

Cons: If there are many subclasses, each with their individual fields, the table becomes "sparse" potentially leading to wasted storage space. When querying the entire rows have to be read always even if you are only interested in a single subclass (although this can be mitigated using non-clustered indexes).

In table-per-type (TPT) mapping, each type in the inheritance hierarchy is mapped to its individual table and all tables are linked by a common ID:

```
CREATE TABLE LibraryItem
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    -- Shared by all types 
    Title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   -- Shared by all types 
)  

CREATE TABLE PersonalLibraryItem 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    -- Shared by all types 
    UserID INT NOT NULL             -- Note NOT NULL 
)  

CREATE TABLE SystemLibraryItem
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    -- Shared by all types 
    SystemItemAttr INT NOT NULL     -- Note NOT NULL 
)
```

Pros: No wasted columns and no wasted space. If only querying one subclass, only data belonging to that subclass has to be read.

Cons: Individual tables have to be joined if querying multiple subclasses, so performance suffers.

Choosing between the two patterns is a balancing act and depends on a number of factors, including how many subclasses are in the hierarchy, how many fields those subclasses have, and how the data is queried.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good point about ORM. Yes I am using the EF ORM. Forgot about this, perhaps my mindset is too relational !!!

Comment: Now read more fully. I usually use a TPT pattern since my mindset is relational, and then normalise out the tables. However I have started to use "Topic Specific" DB Views that map onto more generic physical tables. Yes I could run into sparsity issues, but as you mention there are DB mechanisms to deal with this. The interesting point is whether using a DB View is better or worse than using a TPH approach in the ORM?

Comment: No I do not use TPT, I got confused. I actually do not use TPT or TPH at present just straight forward Entity / Table or View mapping.